# merge 1 commit from 1 branch to the master?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

I've read [this book section](https://book.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) about git branches.

I have create a branch called 'experimental'. I switch to that branch and make 2 commits there.  So if it possible for me to merge the later commit (the 2nd of the 2 commits) of the experiment to the master branch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) command. There are a few other alternative methods that you might consider as well. Check out the article [Pick Out Individual Commits](http://www.gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/04/pick-out-individual-commits.html) on Git Ready.